# Regex "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?i).concat\\([ -~]*\\ " is causing catastrophic backtracking for large string

Tags: java, regex

Regex "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?i).concat\([ -~]*\ " is causing  catastrophic backtracking while trying to find the match(matcher.find()) in java for large string.
How can i modify this regex pattern to avoid this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It shouldn't be causing catastrophic backtracking. At least I can't see any of the traditional reasons for that. Are you sure this is the entire regex?

Comment: Please provide the sample string you have issue with. Use pastebin service. Also, explain what matches you expect.

Comment: The sample string should be pasted into the question, if possible.

Comment: The hyphen in the middle of the character class [ -~]* means the regex will try to match a range space through ~, which might cause unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I am trying to find and remove the string if it has strings like this "somevariable.concat(anything)".

Comment: It is happening if the string length is small. But  when i am trying to find in a string which has string length has morethan 1lak it hangs.

Comment: The strings are like the following "<script>something.concat(sdf)</script>FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB0043000302020302020303030304030304050805050404050A070706080C0A.........etc."   I want to remove the "something.concat(sdf)" only which is mentioned inside the script tag.